# Should I Post a Variation as an Update or New Post?

Tags: discussion

I made a puzzle recently ([Spelling Beelzebub](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92308/spelling-beelzebub)) that was solved very quickly. In response, I have made a harder version that requires taking into account multiple words. 
[image: Spelling Bee Two]
Should this be posted as an update to the original, as a new post, or not at all?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be an entirely independent question, not an update to the original, so it should be posted separately.